# Implementing Push Notification on iPhone 5.1

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

i tried to implement push notification on my iPhone application. I have created the provisional profile successfully. while i tried to read my device token using the following code.

```
 
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:\n%@", deviceToken);
    viewController.tokenTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", deviceToken];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    viewController.tokenTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Failed to get Device Token: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
}
```

throws Error as

> didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application

Afterwards i have cleaned and recreated the whole certificates and proceed again. still same problem occurs.
and i have also tried with the sample application from git hub
https://github.com/damondanieli/Z2NotifyMe

> *can anyone reply how to solve or how to identify the erroneous part?*

Comment: how are you planning to send the push notifications? Do you have your own server set up or are you using a 3rd party service such as Urban Airship?

Comment: i have planed to setup my server on java.